# How to solve the Error with Invalid number of bars back

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Could someone help me with an error on Pinescript version 5?

I recieve this message when the indicator is loaded by tradingview:

> Invalid number of bars back [-1] within the history-referencing operator. The value must be >= 0

[image: see error]

I had reviewed the source code but I’m no an skilled pinescript developer yet as to find the root cause on this error. I mean, I used google in order to get some insight about and also I have checked some Documentation but either I tried to read the source code it was unsuccessful as far :(

Could it be that some good Samaritan will be able to help me find the root cause of that error so that I can help me solve it?

I will be immensely grateful for any help.

```
//@version=5
persistent_bull = 0.0
persistent_bear = 0.0
persistent_bull := nz(persistent_bull[1], 0)
persistent_bear := nz(persistent_bear[1], 0)

indicator(title='Indicator for Crypto', shorttitle='$', overlay=true, max_bars_back=500)
// ****************************************Inputs***************************************************************
buySellSignal = input(true, 'Show the buy sell signals?')
cogRegionFillTransp = input(false, 'Display COG & ATR Starc+/-?')
showFibCOG = input(false, 'Display COG FIB based S(upport) and R(esistance)?')
inputIndividualSiganlPlot = true
sp = input(false, 'Display Parabolic SAR - SAR?')
spLines = sp ? true : false
sCloud = input(false, 'Display Ichimoku - Ichimoku?')
sL = input(false, 'Display Leledec Exhausion - Leledc?')
sTD = false
sRMO = input(false, 'Display Rahul Mohindar Oscillator - RMO?')
inputAma = input(false, title='Display Kaufman AMA wave - AMA?')
tm = input(false, 'Display Trend Magic signals - TMI?')
wtoLB = input(false, 'Display WaveTrend Oscillator - WTO?')
vfiLB = input(false, 'Display Volume Flow Indicator - VFI?')
maj = input(true, title='Display Major Leledc Exhausion Bar signal - Leledec')
inputNeutralMinorSignals = input(false, title='Display the minor / not strong signals from Ichimoku')
min = input(false, title='Display Minor Leledc Exhausion Bar signal - Leledec')
tenkanPeriods = input.int(10, minval=9, title='Tenkan Period - Ichimoku [(normal)9 or (forex)10 or (crypto)20]')
kijunPeriods = input.int(30, minval=26, title='Kijun Period - Ichimoku [(normal)26 or (forex)30 or (crypto)60]')
chikouPeriods = input.int(60, minval=52, title='Chikou - Ichimoku [(normal)52 or (forex)60 or (crypto)120]')
displacement = input.int(30, minval=26, title='Displacement - Ichimoku [(normal/forex)26 or (crypto)30]')
donate = input(false, title='Donate to btc: 3BMEXPhCHD1QgBGiDmLAWnoyfrr1jwKnQo')
follow = input(false, title='Follow me on twitter @Joy_Bangla_1979')
// ****************************************General Color Variables***************************************************************
colorLime = #006400  // Warning sign for long trade
colorBuy = #2DFF03  // Good sign for long trade
colorSell = #733629  // Good sign for short trade
colorMaroon = #8b0000  // Warning sign for short trade
colorBlue = #0000ff  // No clear sign
colorGray = #a9a9a9  // Gray Color (For Squeeze momentum indicator)
colorBlack = #000000  // Black
colorWhite = #ffffff  // White
colorTenkanViolet = #800000  // Tenkan-sen line color
colorKijun = #0000A6  // Kijun-sen line color

// TD Sequential bar colors
tdSell = #ff6666
tdSellOvershoot = #ff1a1a
tdSellOvershoot1 = #cc0000
tdSellOverShoot2 = #990000
tdSellOverShoot3 = #732626

tdBuy = #80ff80
tdBuyOverShoot = #33ff33
tdBuyOvershoot1 = #00cc00
tdBuyOverShoot2 = #008000
tdBuyOvershoot3 = #004d00

barBuy = #006a4e
barSell = #c91f37

// ****************************************Icons***************************************************************
upSign = '↑'  // indicates the indicator shows uptrend
downSign = '↓'  // incicates the indicator showing downtrend
exitSign = 'x'  //indicates the indicator uptrend/downtrend ending
// diamond signals weakBullishSignal or weakBearishsignal
// flag signals neutralBullishSignal or neutralBearishSignal

// ****************************************Parabolic SAR code***************************************************************
start = 2
increment = 2
maximum = 2
sus = true
sds = true
disc = false

startCalc = start * .01
incrementCalc = increment * .01
maximumCalc = maximum * .10

sarUp = ta.sar(startCalc, incrementCalc, maximumCalc)
sarDown = ta.sar(startCalc, incrementCalc, maximumCalc)

colUp = spLines and close >= sarDown ? colorLime : na
colDown = spLines and close <= sarUp ? colorSell : na

plot(sp and sus and sarUp ? sarUp : na, title='↓ SAR', style=plot.style_cross, linewidth=3, color=colUp)
plot(sp and sds and sarDown ? sarDown : na, title='↑ SAR', style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=3, color=colDown)

startSAR = 0.02
incrementSAR = 0.02
maximumSAR = 0.2

psar = ta.sar(startSAR, incrementSAR, maximumSAR)
//bullishPSAR = psar < high and psar[1] > low
//bearishPSAR = psar > low and psar[1] < high
bullishPSAR = psar < high and psar[0] > low //  BarsBack
bearishPSAR = psar > low and psar[0] < high //BarsBack


//***********************Leledc Exhausion Bar***********************************************
leledcSrc = input(close, 'Major Leledec Exhausion Bar ::  Source')
maj_qual = input(6, 'Major Leledec Exhausion Bar ::  Bar count no')
maj_len = input(30, 'Major Leledec Exhausion Bar ::  Highest / Lowest')
min_qual = input(5, 'Minor Leledec Exhausion Bar ::  Bar count no')
min_len = input(5, 'Minor Leledec Exhausion Bar ::  Bar count no')


lele(qual, len) =>
    var bindex = 0  // declare and initialize 'bindex' to 0
    var sindex = 0
    var ret = 0
    if leledcSrc > leledcSrc[4]
        bindex += 1
        bindex
    if leledcSrc < leledcSrc[4]
        sindex += 1
        sindex
    if bindex > qual and leledcSrc < open and high >= ta.highest(high, len)
        bindex := 0
        ret := -1
        ret
    if sindex > qual and leledcSrc > open and low <= ta.lowest(low, len)
        sindex := 0
        ret := 1
        ret
    ret

major = lele(maj_qual, maj_len)
minor = lele(min_qual, min_len)

leledecMajorBullish = maj and lele(maj_qual, maj_len) == 1 ? low : na
leledecMajorBearish = maj and lele(maj_qual, maj_len) == -1 ? high : na


//****************Ichimoku ************************************
donchian(len) =>
    math.avg(ta.lowest(len), ta.highest(len))

tenkan = donchian(tenkanPeriods)
kijun = donchian(kijunPeriods)
senkouA = math.avg(tenkan, kijun)
senkouB = donchian(chikouPeriods)
displacedSenkouA = senkouA[displacement]
displacedSenkouB = senkouB[displacement]

bullishSignal = ta.crossover(tenkan, kijun)
bearishSignal = ta.crossunder(tenkan, kijun)

bullishSignalValues = bullishSignal ? tenkan : na
bearishSignalValues = bearishSignal ? tenkan : na

strongBullishSignal = ta.crossover(tenkan, kijun) and bullishSignalValues > displacedSenkouA and bullishSignalValues > displacedSenkouB and low > tenkan and displacedSenkouA > displacedSenkouB
strongBearishSignal = bearishSignalValues < displacedSenkouA and bearishSignalValues < displacedSenkouB and high < tenkan and displacedSenkouA < displacedSenkouB

neutralBullishSignal = bullishSignalValues > displacedSenkouA and bullishSignalValues < displacedSenkouB or bullishSignalValues < displacedSenkouA and bullishSignalValues > displacedSenkouB
weakBullishSignal = bullishSignalValues < displacedSenkouA and bullishSignalValues < displacedSenkouB
neutralBearishSignal = bearishSignalValues > displacedSenkouA and bearishSignalValues < displacedSenkouB or bearishSignalValues < displacedSenkouA and bearishSignalValues > displacedSenkouB
weakBearishSignal = bearishSignalValues > displacedSenkouA and bearishSignalValues > displacedSenkouB

//*********************Kaufman AMA wave*********************//
srcAMA = input(close, 'Kaufman AMA wave ::  Source')
lengthAMA = input(20, 'Kaufman AMA wave ::  Length')
filterp = input(10, 'Kaufman AMA wave ::  Efficiency Ratio')

d = math.abs(srcAMA - srcAMA[1])
s = math.abs(srcAMA - srcAMA[lengthAMA])
noise = math.sum(d, lengthAMA)
efratio = s / noise
fastsc = input(0.6022, 'Kaufman AMA wave ::  Fastsc')
slowsc = input(0.0645, 'Kaufman AMA wave ::  Slowsc')

//ama & amalow & amalow
ama = 0.0
amalow = 0.0
amahigh = 0.0

smooth = math.pow(efratio * fastsc + slowsc, 2)
ama := nz(ama[1], srcAMA) + smooth * (srcAMA - nz(ama[1], srcAMA))
filter = filterp / 100 * ta.stdev(ama - nz(ama), lengthAMA)
amalow := ama < nz(ama[1]) ? ama : nz(amalow[1])
amahigh := ama > nz(ama[1]) ? ama : nz(amahigh[1])
bw = ama - amalow > filter ? 1 : amahigh - ama > filter ? -1 : 0
s_color = bw > 0 ? colorBuy : bw < 0 ? colorSell : colorBlue

amaLongConditionEntry = s_color == colorBuy and s_color[1] != colorBuy
amaShortConditionEntry = s_color == colorSell and s_color[1] != colorSell
//***********************Rahul Mohindar Oscillator ******************************//
AMASRC = input(close, 'Rahul Mohindar Oscillator ::  Source')
cm2(x) =>
    ta.sma(x, 2)
ma1 = cm2(AMASRC)
ma2 = cm2(ma1)
ma3 = cm2(ma2)
ma4 = cm2(ma3)
ma5 = cm2(ma4)
ma6 = cm2(ma5)
ma7 = cm2(ma6)
ma8 = cm2(ma7)
ma9 = cm2(ma8)
ma10 = cm2(ma9)
SwingTrd1 = 100 * (AMASRC - (ma1 + ma2 + ma3 + ma4 + ma5 + ma6 + ma7 + ma8 + ma9 + ma10) / 10) / (ta.highest(AMASRC, 10) - ta.lowest(AMASRC, 10))
SwingTrd2 = ta.ema(SwingTrd1, 30)
SwingTrd3 = ta.ema(SwingTrd2, 30)
RMO = ta.ema(SwingTrd1, 81)
Buy = ta.cross(SwingTrd2, SwingTrd3)
Sell = ta.cross(SwingTrd3, SwingTrd2)
Bull_Trend = ta.ema(SwingTrd1, 81) > 0
Bear_Trend = ta.ema(SwingTrd1, 81) < 0
Ribbon_kol = Bull_Trend ? colorBuy : Bear_Trend ? colorSell : colorBlue
Impulse_UP = SwingTrd2 > 0
Impulse_Down = RMO < 0
bar_kol = Impulse_UP ? colorBuy : Impulse_Down ? colorSell : Bull_Trend ? colorBuy : colorBlue

rahulMohindarOscilllatorLongEntry = Ribbon_kol == colorBuy and Ribbon_kol[1] != colorBuy and Ribbon_kol[1] == colorSell and bar_kol == colorBuy
rahulMohindarOscilllatorShortEntry = Ribbon_kol == colorSell and Ribbon_kol[1] != colorSell and Ribbon_kol[1] == colorBuy and bar_kol == colorSell

//***********************TD Sequential code ******************************//
transp = 0
Numbers = false
SR = false
Barcolor = true

//TD & TS
TD = 0.0
TS = 0.0

TD := close > close[4] ? nz(TD[1]) + 1 : 0
TS := close < close[4] ? nz(TS[1]) + 1 : 0

TDUp = TD - ta.valuewhen(TD < TD[1], TD, 1)
TDDn = TS - ta.valuewhen(TS < TS[1], TS, 1)

priceflip = ta.barssince(close < close[4])
sellsetup = close > close[4] and priceflip
sell = sellsetup and ta.barssince(priceflip != 9)
sellovershoot = sellsetup and ta.barssince(priceflip != 13)
sellovershoot1 = sellsetup and ta.barssince(priceflip != 14)
sellovershoot2 = sellsetup and ta.barssince(priceflip != 15)
sellovershoot3 = sellsetup and ta.barssince(priceflip != 16)

priceflip1 = ta.barssince(close > close[4])
buysetup = close < close[4] and priceflip1
buy = buysetup and ta.barssince(priceflip1 != 9)
buyovershoot = ta.barssince(priceflip1 != 13) and buysetup
buyovershoot1 = ta.barssince(priceflip1 != 14) and buysetup
buyovershoot2 = ta.barssince(priceflip1 != 15) and buysetup
buyovershoot3 = ta.barssince(priceflip1 != 16) and buysetup

TDbuyh = ta.valuewhen(buy, high, 0)
TDbuyl = ta.valuewhen(buy, low, 0)
TDsellh = ta.valuewhen(sell, high, 0)
TDselll = ta.valuewhen(sell, low, 0)


//***********************Volume Flow Indicator [LazyBear] ******************************//
lengthVFI = input(130, title='Volume Flow Indicator :: length')
coefVFI = input(0.2, title='Volume Flow Indicator  ::  Coef')
vcoefVFI = input(2.5, title='Volume Flow Indicator ::  Max. vol. cutoff')
signalLength = input(5, title='Volume Flow Indicator ::  signal length')
smoothVFI = input(false, title='Volume Flow  :: Indicator smooth?')
ma(x, y) =>
    smoothVFI ? ta.sma(x, y) : x

typical = hlc3
inter = math.log(typical) - math.log(typical[1])
vinter = ta.stdev(inter, 30)
cutoff = coefVFI * vinter * close
vave = ta.sma(volume, lengthVFI)[1]
vmax = vave * vcoefVFI
vc = volume < vmax ? volume : vmax
mf = typical - typical[1]
iff_1 = mf < -cutoff ? -vc : 0
vcp = mf > cutoff ? vc : iff_1

vfi = ma(math.sum(vcp, lengthVFI) / vave, 3)
vfima = ta.ema(vfi, signalLength)
dVFI = vfi - vfima

bullishVFI = vfi > 0 and vfi[1] <= 0
bearishVFI = vfi < 0 and vfi[1] >= 0

//***********************WaveTrend Oscillator [WT] ******************************//
n1 = input(10, 'WaveTrend Oscillator:: Channel Length')
n2 = input(21, 'WaveTrend Oscillator:: Average Length')
obLevel1 = input(60, 'WaveTrend Oscillator:: Over Bought Level 1')
obLevel2 = input(53, 'WaveTrend Oscillator:: Over Bought Level 2')
osLevel1 = input(-60, 'WaveTrend Oscillator:: Over Sold Level 1')
osLevel2 = input(-53, 'WaveTrend Oscillator:: Over Sold Level 2')

ap = hlc3
esa = ta.ema(ap, n1)
dWTI = ta.ema(math.abs(ap - esa), n1)
ci = (ap - esa) / (0.015 * dWTI)
tci = ta.ema(ci, n2)

wt1 = tci
wt2 = ta.sma(wt1, 4)

wtiSignal = wt1 - wt2

bullishWTI = wt1 > osLevel1 and wt1[1] <= osLevel1 and wtiSignal > 0
bearishWTI = wt1 < obLevel1 and wt1[1] >= obLevel1 and wtiSignal < 0

// **************** Trend Magic code adapted from  Glaz ********************* /
CCI = input(20, 'Input for CCI')
ATR = input(5, 'Input for ATRc')
Multiplier = input(1.0, 'ATR Multiplier')
original = input(true)

thisCCI = ta.cci(close, CCI)
lastCCI = na(thisCCI[1]) ? thisCCI : thisCCI[1]

trr = ta.tr(true)  //renombrada de tr a trr
bufferDn = high + Multiplier * ta.sma(ta.tr, ATR)
bufferUp = low - Multiplier * ta.sma(ta.tr, ATR)

bufferUp := thisCCI >= 0 and lastCCI < 0 ? bufferDn[1] : bufferUp
bufferDn := thisCCI <= 0 and lastCCI > 0 ? bufferUp[1] : bufferDn

var x = 0.0
var swap = 0
var swap2 = color.red
var swap3 = color.red
var swap4 = color.red

x := thisCCI >= 0 ? bufferUp : thisCCI <= 0 ? bufferDn : x[1]
swap := x > x[1] ? 1 : x < x[1] ? -1 : swap[1]
swap2 := swap == 1 ? color.lime : color.red
swap3 := thisCCI >= 0 ? color.lime : color.red
swap4 := original ? swap3 : swap2

bullTrendMagic = swap4 == color.lime and swap4[1] == color.red
bearTrendMagic = swap4 == color.red and swap4[1] == color.lime


//********** Indicator: Support/Resistance based on COG Fib by Lazy Bear ****************

lengthFibCOG = input.int(20, "Period")
srcFibCOG = input(close, "Source")

calc_wima(src, length) =>
    var float MA_s = 0.0
    MA_s := (src + nz(MA_s[1] * (length - 1))) / length
    MA_s

calc_ma(s, l) =>
    ta.sma(s, l)

medianCOG = input.float(0.0, "Median")

th = ta.linreg(high, lengthFibCOG, math.round(medianCOG))
tl = ta.linreg(low, lengthFibCOG, math.round(medianCOG))
tr_c = th - tl
tra = calc_wima(tr_c, lengthFibCOG)

mp = calc_ma(srcFibCOG, lengthFibCOG)
ub_4p2360 = mp + 4.2360 * tra
ub_3p6180 = mp + 3.6180 * tra
ub_2p6180 = mp + 2.6180 * tra
ub_1p6180 = mp + 1.6180 * tra
ub_0p618 = mp + 0.618 * tra

lb_1p6180 = mp - 1.6180 * tra
lb_2p6180 = mp - 2.6180 * tra
lb_3p6180 = mp - 3.6180 * tra
lb_4p2360 = mp - 4.2360 * tra
lb_0p618 = mp - 0.618 * tra


line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=mp, x2=bar_index + 1, y2=mp, color=color.maroon, width=4)
line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=lb_0p618, x2=bar_index + 1, y2=lb_0p618, color=color.black, width=3)
line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=ub_0p618, x2=bar_index + 1, y2=ub_0p618, color=color.black, width=3)
line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=ub_1p6180, x2=bar_index + 1, y2=ub_1p6180, color=color.lime, width=2)
line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=lb_1p6180, x2=bar_index + 1, y2=lb_1p6180, color=color.lime, width=3)
line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=ub_2p6180, x2=bar_index + 1, y2=ub_2p6180, color=color.red, width=1)
line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=lb_2p6180, x2=bar_index + 1, y2=lb_2p6180, color=color.red, width=1)
line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=ub_3p6180, x2=bar_index + 1, y2=ub_3p6180, color=color.purple, width=1)
line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=lb_3p6180, x2=bar_index + 1, y2=lb_3p6180, color=color.purple, width=1)
line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=ub_4p2360, x2=bar_index + 1, y2=ub_4p2360, color=color.blue, width=1)
line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=lb_4p2360, x2=bar_index + 1, y2=lb_4p2360, color=color.blue, width=1)



// ************ Indicator: Custom COG channel by Lazy Bear **************** //
srcCOG = input(close, title='COG (Center of Gravity) channel ::  Source')
lengthCOG = input(34, title='COG (Center of Gravity)  channel ::  Length')
median = input(0, title='COG (Center of Gravity)  channel  ::  median')
multCOG = input(2.5, title='COG (Center of Gravity)  channel  ::  mult')
offset = input(20, title='COG (Center of Gravity)  channel ::  offset')

tr_custom() =>
    x1 = high - low
    x2 = math.abs(high - close[1])
    x3 = math.abs(low - close[1])
    math.max(x1, math.max(x2, x3))

atr_custom(x, y) =>
    ta.sma(x, y)

dev = multCOG * ta.stdev(srcCOG, lengthCOG)
basis = ta.linreg(srcCOG, lengthCOG, median)
ul = basis + dev
ll = basis - dev
tr_v = tr_custom()
acustom = 2 * atr_custom(tr_v, lengthCOG)
uls = basis + acustom
lls = basis - acustom

cRFT = cogRegionFillTransp ? 0 : 100

// Plot STDEV channel

len = bar_index - 1  // get the last index of the data
basis1 = ta.sma(close, 20)
ul1 = basis1 + ta.stdev(close, 20)*2
ll1 = basis1 - ta.stdev(close, 20)*2

G_median_stdev_line = line.new(x1 = len, y1 = basis1[len], x2 = bar_index, y2 = basis1, width = 2, color = color.new(color.navy, 50), style = line.style_solid)
coG_bb_plus_line = line.new(x1 = len, y1 = ul1[len], x2 = bar_index, y2 = ul1, width = 2, color = color.new(color.red, 50), style = line.style_dashed)
coG_bb_minus_line = line.new(x1 = len, y1 = ll1[len], x2 = bar_index, y2 = ll1, width = 2, color = color.new(color.green, 50), style = line.style_dashed)

// Plot ATR channel
var basis_line = plot(basis, color=color.navy, linewidth=2)
var ls = plot(uls, color=color.red, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_circles)
var ts = plot(lls, color=color.green, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_circles)

// Mark SQZ
plot_offs_high = 0.002
plot_offs_low = 0.002
sqz_f = uls > ul and lls < ll
b_color = sqz_f ? color.black : na
plot(sqz_f ? lls - (lls * plot_offs_low) : na, color=b_color, style=plot.style_cross, linewidth=3, title="COG SQZ", transp=0) 
plot(sqz_f ? uls + (uls * plot_offs_high) : na, color=b_color, style=plot.style_cross, linewidth=3, title="COG SQZ", transp=0)


// ****************************************All the plots and coloring of bars***************************************************************
// Trend Magic
plotchar(tm and bullTrendMagic, title='TM', char=upSign, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(colorBuy, 0), text='TM', textcolor=color.new(colorBuy, 0), size=size.auto)
plotchar(tm and bearTrendMagic, title='TM', char=downSign, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(colorSell, 0), text='TM', textcolor=color.new(colorSell, 0), size=size.auto)

// WaveTrend Oscillator
plotshape(wtoLB and bullishWTI, color=color.new(colorBuy, 0), style=shape.labelup, textcolor=color.new(#000000, 0), text='WTI', location=location.belowbar)
plotshape(wtoLB and bearishWTI, color=color.new(colorSell, 0), style=shape.labeldown, textcolor=color.new(#ffffff, 0), text='WTI', location=location.abovebar)

// VFI
plotshape(vfiLB and bullishVFI, color=color.new(colorBuy, 0), style=shape.labelup, textcolor=color.new(#000000, 0), text='VFI', location=location.belowbar)
plotshape(vfiLB and bearishVFI, color=color.new(colorSell, 0), style=shape.labeldown, textcolor=color.new(#ffffff, 0), text='VFI', location=location.abovebar)

// PSAR
plotshape(inputIndividualSiganlPlot and sp and bullishPSAR, color=color.new(colorBuy, 0), style=shape.labelup, textcolor=color.new(#000000, 0), text='Sar', location=location.belowbar)
plotshape(inputIndividualSiganlPlot and sp and bearishPSAR, color=color.new(colorSell, 0), style=shape.labeldown, textcolor=color.new(#ffffff, 0), text='Sar', location=location.abovebar)

// Leledec
plotshape(inputIndividualSiganlPlot and sL and leledecMajorBearish, color=colorSell, style=shape.labeldown, textcolor=#ffffff,  text="Leledec", location=location.abovebar, transp=0)
plotshape(inputIndividualSiganlPlot and sL and leledecMajorBullish, color=colorBuy, style=shape.labelup, textcolor=#000000, text="Leledec", location=location.belowbar, transp=0)

plotshape(major == 1 ? minor == 1 ? low : na : na, style=shape.diamond, text='Leledec', size=size.tiny, location=location.belowbar, title='Leledec :: Weak', color=color.new(color.lime, 0))
plotshape(major == 1 ? minor == -1 ? high : na : na, style=shape.diamond, text='Leledec', size=size.tiny, location=location.abovebar, title='Leleddec :: Weak', color=color.new(color.red, 0))
plotshape(min ? minor == 1 ? low : na : na, style=shape.diamond, text='Leledec', size=size.tiny, location=location.belowbar, title='Leledec :: Weak', color=color.new(colorLime, 0))
plotshape(min ? minor == -1 ? high : na : na, style=shape.diamond, text='Leledec', size=size.tiny, location=location.abovebar, title='Leleddec :: Weak', color=color.new(colorSell, 0))



// Ichimoku
//-----------------------------------------------------------------//
// Input variables
tenkanII = input.int(title='Tenkan', defval=9, minval=1)
kijunII = input.int(title='Kijun', defval=26, minval=1)
displacementII = input.int(title='Displacement', defval=26, minval=1)
ichimokuSrc = input(title='Ichimoku:: Source', defval=close)

// Color variables
colorTenkanVioletII = color.new(#af58db, 100)
colorKijunII = color.new(#ff6c58, 100)
colorSellII = color.new(#ff6c58, 100)
colorBuyII = color.new(#00c300, 100)
colorLimeII = color.new(#00ff00, 100)

// Cloud variables
senkouAII = (tenkanII + kijunII) / 2
senkouBII = ta.sma(ichimokuSrc, kijunII)
sCloudII = ichimokuSrc >= senkouA and ichimokuSrc >= senkouB

// Define series for each plot
tenkanSeries = sCloudII ? tenkanII : na
kijunSeries = sCloudII ? kijunII : na
chikouSeries = sCloudII ? request.security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe.period, ichimokuSrc, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_off, -displacementII) : na

senkouASeries = senkouAII > senkouBII ? (sCloudII ? senkouA : na) : na
senkouBSeries = senkouAII > senkouBII ? (sCloudII ? senkouB : na) : na
colorSeries = senkouAII > senkouBII ? (sCloudII ? color.new(#1eb600, 100) : na) : (sCloudII ? colorSellII : na)

// Plot each series
plot(tenkanSeries, color=colorTenkanVioletII, title='Tenkan', linewidth=2)
plot(kijunSeries, color=colorKijunII, title='Kijun', linewidth=2)
plot(chikouSeries, color=colorLimeII, title='Chikou', linewidth=1)
plot(senkouASeries, color=colorSeries, title="Ichimoku :: Kumo")

// Plot signals using plotshape
var inputIndividualSignalPlotII = input.bool(title="Individual Signal Plot", defval=true)
var inputNeutralMinorSignalsII = input.bool(title="Neutral Minor Signals", defval=true)

strongBearishSignalII = 1
strongBullishSignalII = 2
neutralBullishSignalII = 3
weakBullishSignalII = 4

plotshape(inputIndividualSignalPlotII and strongBearishSignalII, color=color.new(colorSellII, 0), style=shape.labelup, textcolor=color.new(#000000, 0), text='Ichimoku', location=location.abovebar)
plotshape(inputIndividualSignalPlotII and strongBullishSignalII, color=color.new(colorBuyII, 0), style=shape.labeldown, textcolor=color.new(#000000, 0), text='Ichimoku', location=location.belowbar)

plotshape(inputNeutralMinorSignals and neutralBullishSignalII, color=color.new(colorSellII, 0), style=shape.labelup, textcolor=color.new(#000000, 0), text='Ichimoku', location=location.abovebar)
plotshape(inputNeutralMinorSignals and weakBullishSignalII, color=color.new(colorBuyII, 0), style=shape.labeldown, textcolor=color.new(#000000, 0), text='Ichimoku', location=location.belowbar)



//-----------------------------------------------------------------//

// AMA
plotshape(inputIndividualSiganlPlot and inputAma and amaLongConditionEntry, color=color.new(colorBuy, 0), style=shape.labelup, textcolor=color.new(#000000, 0), text='AMA', location=location.belowbar)
plotshape(inputIndividualSiganlPlot and inputAma and amaShortConditionEntry, color=color.new(colorSell, 0), style=shape.labeldown, textcolor=color.new(#ffffff, 0), text='AMA', location=location.abovebar)

// RMO
plotshape(inputIndividualSiganlPlot and sRMO and rahulMohindarOscilllatorLongEntry, color=color.new(colorBuy, 0), style=shape.labelup, textcolor=color.new(#000000, 0), text='RMO', location=location.belowbar)
plotshape(inputIndividualSiganlPlot and sRMO and rahulMohindarOscilllatorShortEntry, color=color.new(colorSell, 0), style=shape.labeldown, textcolor=color.new(#ffffff, 0), text='RMO', location=location.abovebar)

// TD
//--------------------------//
lineBuffer1 = sTD and SR?(TDbuyh ? TDbuyl: na):na
lineBuffer2 = sTD and SR?(TDselll ? TDsellh : na):na

plot(lineBuffer1, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1, color=color.red, display=display.none)
plot(lineBuffer2, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1, color=color.lime, display=display.none)

var color sColor = color.red
var color bColor = color.lime

barColour = sell ? tdSell : buy ? tdBuy : sellovershoot ? tdSellOvershoot : sellovershoot1 ? tdSellOvershoot1 : sellovershoot2 ? tdSellOverShoot2 : sellovershoot3 ? tdSellOverShoot3 : buyovershoot ? tdBuyOverShoot : buyovershoot1 ? tdBuyOvershoot1 : buyovershoot2 ? tdBuyOverShoot2 : buyovershoot3 ? tdBuyOvershoot3 : na
barcolor(color=barColour, title='TD Sequential ::  Bar Colour')
//---------------------------//



// ****************************************BUY/SELL Signal ***************************************************************
bull = leledecMajorBullish or strongBullishSignal or rahulMohindarOscilllatorLongEntry or bullishVFI or amaLongConditionEntry or bullTrendMagic or bullishWTI
bear = leledecMajorBearish or bearishPSAR or strongBearishSignal or rahulMohindarOscilllatorShortEntry or bearishVFI or amaShortConditionEntry or bearTrendMagic or bearishWTI

if bull
    persistent_bull := 1
    persistent_bear := 0
    persistent_bear

if bear
    persistent_bull := 0
    persistent_bear := 1
    persistent_bear

plotshape(buySellSignal and bull and (persistent_bull[1] != 1 or bear), style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(colorBuy, 0), text='Buy', textcolor=color.new(#000000, 0))
plotshape(buySellSignal and bear and (persistent_bear[1] != 1 or bull), style=shape.labeldown, color=color.new(colorSell, 0), text='Sell', location=location.abovebar, textcolor=color.new(#ffffff, 0))
// ****************************************Alerts***************************************************************
// For global buy/sell
alertcondition(bull and persistent_bull[1] != 1, title='Buy', message='Buy')
alertcondition(bear and persistent_bear[1] != 1, title='Short', message='Short')

// For WaveTrend Oscillator
alertcondition(bullishWTI, title='Bullish - WaveTrend Oscillator', message='Bullish - WaveTrend Oscillator')
alertcondition(bearishWTI, title='Bearish - WaveTrend Oscillator', message='Bearish - WaveTrend Oscillator')

// For Volume Flow Indicator
alertcondition(bullishVFI, title='Bullish - Volume Flow Indicator', message='Bullish - Volume Flow Indicator')
alertcondition(bearishVFI, title='Bearish - Volume Flow Indicator', message='Bearish - Volume Flow Indicator')

// For major Leledc Exhausion
alertcondition(leledecMajorBullish, title='Bullish - Leledec Exhausion', message='Bullish - Leledec Exhausion')
alertcondition(leledecMajorBearish, title='Bearish - Leledec Exhausion', message='Bearish - Leledec Exhausion')

// For Kaufman AMA wave
alertcondition(amaLongConditionEntry, title='Bullish - Kaufman AMA wave', message='Bullish - AMA ::  Kaufman AMA wave')
alertcondition(amaShortConditionEntry, title='Bearish - Kaufman AMA wave', message='Bearish - AMA :: Kaufman AMA wave')

// For Rahul Mohindar Oscillator
alertcondition(rahulMohindarOscilllatorLongEntry, title='Bullish - Rahul Mohindar Oscillator', message='Bullish - RMO :: Rahul Mohindar Oscillator')
alertcondition(rahulMohindarOscilllatorShortEntry, title='Bearish - Rahul Mohindar Oscillator', message='Bearish - RMO :: Rahul Mohindar Oscillator')

// For Parabolic Sar
alertcondition(bullishPSAR, title='Bullish - Sar :: Parabolic SAR', message='Bullish - Sar :: Parabolic SAR')
alertcondition(bearishPSAR, title='Bearish - Sar :: Parabolic SAR', message='Bearish - Sar :: Parabolic SAR')

// For Ichimoku
alertcondition(strongBullishSignal, title='Bullish - Ichimoku', message='Bullish Ichimoku- Ichimoku')
alertcondition(strongBearishSignal, title='Bearish - Ichimoku', message='Bearish Ichimoku - Ichimoku')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is made of several indicators, you must isolate them and add them one by one until you see the error.

This error occurs because you try to get a past bar with a negative number.

In pinescript you can't use (for example) :

```
MyVar = close[-1]
```

In this case if you want the preceding value, you should use :

```
MyVar = close[1]
```